# Is it natural to use the verb "read" on its own not metioning what someone read?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to use the verb "read" on its own not mentioning what someone read? For example:

> Person A: Did you **read** yesterday?
>
> Person B: Yes, I **read** a lot yesterday.

Comment: I'm guessing both persons would know what is being referred to (school book, a poem, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "read" can be used in a transitive or intransitive way. The transitive use is more common, but the intransitive denotes the act of reading without reference to what was read.

Comment: ***My*** question is whether ***a lot*** is the "direct object" of a *transitive* verb usage, or an "adverbial" element modifying an *intransitive* usage in OP's specific context. It would presumably be the former in something like *She accepted some, but rejected a lot*, and the latter in *She cries a lot.* Any opinions?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I did a lot of reading. Would be correct to say "I read yesterday"?

Comment: @FF I think your question permits different answers. "Book" in "I read a book yesterday" would typically be described as a direct object. "Extensively" in "I read extensiively yesterday" would typically be described as an adverb. Looking at the form of "I read a lot yesterday" suggests describing "lot" as a direct object. Looking at meaning suggests describing "a lot" as an adverbial phrase. Grammar is a way to describe language systematically and generally; there can be more than one way to do that.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope No. "I read yesterday" gives no indication of how long or how attentively you read, nor does it indicate what you read. If you want to indicate that you read for a long time you need to insert an adverb or adverbial phrase to modify the very general information that you read at least one word at least one time yesterday. For example, "I read attentively for many hours yesterday." Duration is not implied by the verb "read."